# How to implement user login on Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to implement a very simple login form with Zend framework; however I'm having trouble in understanding how it works.

I have my HTML form with a `username` field, `password` and `submit` elements. I don't know how to validate the username and password.

How do I do this without using Zend Form?

Comment: Have you *completed* the [Getting started with Zend Framwork 2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/overview.html#getting-started-with-zend-framework-2) official user guide? If not, it would be *extremely* difficult to give you any kind of useful answer without the basic knowledge.

Comment: Great. I would recommend updating your question to be more specific on your issue. 'How do I do this without using Zend Form?' is a quite broad. Do you have a specific reason not to want to use `Zend\Form` or is it because you are not quite sure on how to use it? In either case adding any relevant code you already have will help us answer your question.

Comment: @AlexP Noted with thanks. It's a personal preference I guess.

Comment: Have a look here; http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a browser posts the completed form to the server you can obtain the posted values with your controller like this;

```
$username = $this->params()->fromPost('username');
$password = $this->params()->fromPost('password');
```

It's then down to you to pass these values to whatever authentication mechanism you want to use. For example you could perform a simple database lookup against your user table.

However, life is not simple. You need to think about security. Validating and filtering the values passed from the form, hashing passwords, etc.

You also need to think about how to handle an invalid login, such as re-rendering the form with extra display explaining the failure. Zend\Form can help you with some of these issues.

Comment: thanks for your answers, but I just want to ask, what url do I need to insert for my action attribute of my form if say I want to handle the form using a particular controller?

Comment: Whatever url you want. You use the router to map that url to a controller action.

Answer (score 2):

I would start my taking a look the zfcUser Module, which can be found here;

https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser